# Problems with GNOME, Dbus or Polkit in Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: gnome, python, software-center, dbus

Bug description:
  After upgraded my Ubuntu from 19.10 version to 20.04LTS,  I cannot install, update or remove any software inside "Ubuntu
  Software". I also realized that my credential window doesn't appear if
  I try to install or modify something via "Software & Updates" Ubuntu
  API. I've tried to enable Canonical livepatch and the follow error(s)
  came up:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.AttributeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/dbus/SoftwarePropertiesDBus.py", line 383, in _check_policykit_privilege
  (is_auth, _, details) = self.polkit.CheckAuthorization(
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
  return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
  reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.274 was not provided by any .service files

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 711, in _message_cb
  retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/dbus/SoftwarePropertiesDBus.py", line 345, in SetLivepatchEnabled
  self._check_policykit_privilege(
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/dbus/SoftwarePropertiesDBus.py", line 390, in _check_policykit_privilege
  return self._check_polkit_privilege(sender, conn, privilege)
AttributeError: 'SoftwarePropertiesDBus' object has no attribute '_check_polkit_privilege'
```

There are some APIs, as Sinaptic Package Manager, which were already
  installed and now aren't working any more, but They appear on my
  installed list;